# Conditional props based on a undefined prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to make TypeScript complain on missing props based on a prop that was not passed at all.

Please consider the following example:

```
type MyComponentProps = { isOpen: boolean } & (
    | ({ withButton?: true | undefined | void | never } & { buttonText: string })
    | ({ withButton?: false } & { buttonText?: never })
)

const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = ({ withButton = true, buttonText }) => {
    return <></>
}

const AnotherComponent = () => {
    // TypeScript does not complain, but I wanted it to require `buttonText` when `withButton` is not passed
    return <MyComponent isOpen={false} />
}
```

Is there any way I can change the conditional `MyComponentProps` so that when I don't pass `withButton` at all, it will require `buttonText`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make the `withButton` prop required when its value is `false`, so that it does not match the case where it is missing:

```
type MyComponentProps = { isOpen: boolean } & (
    | ({ withButton?: true | undefined | never } & { buttonText: string }) // If withButton prop is true or missing, buttonText prop is required
    | ({ withButton: false } & { buttonText?: never }) // If withButton prop is false, buttonText prop is forbidden (or at most undefined)
)
```

Now TypeScript properly complains when `withButton` prop is missing, but `buttonText` is missing as well (i.e. it is now required):

```
const AnotherComponent = () => {
    return (<>
        <MyComponent isOpen={false} />
        {/*~~~~~~~~~ Property 'withButton' is missing in type '{ isOpen: false; }' but required in type '{ withButton: false; }'.(2322)  */}
        <MyComponent withButton={true} isOpen={false} />
        {/*~~~~~~~~~ Property 'buttonText' is missing in type '{ withButton: true; isOpen: false; }' but required in type '{ buttonText: string; }'.(2322) */}
        <MyComponent withButton={false} buttonText="should not be there" isOpen={false} />
        {/*~~~~~~~~~ Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.(2322) */}
        <MyComponent withButton={false} isOpen={false} />{/* Okay */}
        <MyComponent withButton={false} buttonText={undefined} isOpen={false} />{/* Okay */}
        <MyComponent withButton={true} buttonText="okay" isOpen={false} />{/* Okay */}
        <MyComponent withButton={undefined} buttonText="okay as well" isOpen={false} />{/* Okay */}
    </>)
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgFlqBhXSAOyXZgAUcwAznAC8cAN5xgAgPJ12ALjgAjCBAA2qdnAC+cAGRwAFOTim4AHyMSA7sBgALAEIBXGDAjsA-IphRn9S2d2ABMkTGBOYIs4TgA3JCgdfXFlV3d2ABUkAA8YRQFfCIBzHQBKOAB6CrgASUw4WwcXNw84MH5JIV9-OGg4ECkBYoAaVJbMnPh2iDBOuCIAR2dgImCTM0tDGzsnNI9FTBQ1AXpdAwklPYnc7xikeMTtcqra+sbd8baOqThD46RRpdxllcl8ZnNMNAlMBgqEtIY+ih4CAIAU4EFQuFIqVyDjyGgPGimKxwB4uHlEMQYAA6ABizAAPMS2GTuHwZgIAHwiKwNHbNdI87oAsbpEHwJ4iblidamIgwZxQLQMzkMiqc8jaSgE9hogCC7AgDgSJI45J5hnKwmlssq1QytCQAGU0FBgGB4MEIEghIb4ATwGoUBFAa5ag0UNwkFE7HB3PMkEsVvQAAZAsWTFMNexcOAp94CjxZn5+tooAQnNZmBMKpVGFW26tMlgszjcTqyLjCMR-E66dWNsxiCoAKgAfhPJ5O4Oy6LBqHAAOQFq6LuYDCvFSRaGh0JcSKSdhS-I4nUg6NdAhNJ1bbuOO-d8ppXA6npDn7SL6mGABMAGYfx-co4BHCotWrJtmVJNt4BXcZu2FXRDzkbteyQfsNQgodRynXCZ34BIaCXdMPHFNcfg3IZ2BKCJ7z3RdtmfcYfD8d8OzkV9-g-S8w0WZZb1o3d6AY0VSMmfJCmo7jv3-QDylA8CsLgZtTVZWD+SuVC310EjrhgYR8AEewIGcNQolLJR6GNIh8HYrse20ypMKU4dx1w6cHXogo3Wo8jfSNOByyGIp2BQJQNDjCA6OEjEwgiaMv1-ACgJAsDB1MFTW3NOD0i0-4kJkFCHPypzXLgaQAGsUAXBT0uUqCzXbHKPDyvtRL07tYqxaMCqPVr0NK0dyqqmq0qU+qW2g7KNPgsREPa8UDIgEbbOQ+y0IwsrKuq1LFKwzKpqambcrELr4uCHSrkW-Blp28sGiQNQ1FWwr1sc9UtpG3bbTVTkcW0IA)

---

> `<MyComponent isOpen={false} />` is expecting `withButton`, but I want it to expect `buttonText`

If you mean that you want the TS error to hint about `buttonText` instead of `withButton`, then just make sure to put last in the union the type that you want TS to use by default for hinting:

```
type MyComponentProps = { isOpen: boolean } & (
    | ({ withButton: false } & { buttonText?: never }) // If withButton prop is false, buttonText prop is forbidden (or at most undefined)
    // Put last in union the type that you want to hint to by default
    | ({ withButton?: true | undefined | never } & { buttonText: string }) // If withButton prop is true or missing, buttonText prop is required
)

const AnotherComponent = () => {
    return (<>
        <MyComponent isOpen={false} />
        {/*~~~~~~~~~ Property 'buttonText' is missing in type '{ isOpen: false; }' but required in type '{ buttonText: string; }'.(2322)  */}
        <MyComponent buttonText="okay as well again" isOpen={false} />{/* Okay */}
    </>)
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgFlqBhXSAOyXZgAUcwAznAC8cAN5xgAgPJ12ALjgAjCBAA2qdnAC+cAGRwAFOTim4AHyMSA7sBgALAEIBXGDAgK4mFGoH1dBhJKru7sACpIAB4wAPyKnABuSFA6AJRwAPQZcACSmHC2Di5uHnBg-JJC3r5IADTKIR4R0WUVUl7QSsAAJt1cRtBwKPAgEALwzux9mMCc3akmZllwPK5waijjklqTwKUO9DR0cA7DcNQQzgUo3CcQcPaz8O7K1HDTKM5qMIumloY2OxORrsOInKDOeiWSbTWZIboWOCJZI6fTiBolcJRGCKcZQWYAczSmWyeQKQOKoVaEDAlXBkLggxAUgEhPqwUxzXg5RpdKIAEdnMAiN1yAtyGgPFsmKxwB4uDjEMQYAA6ABizAAPDK2PLuHwaQIAHwiKzkoog00wCF1DGhLnE4QmsS-OBEGDOKBaTVGzUZI3kbSUSXsLYAQXYEAOUFlHAVpsM6Sd4ldyzCtCQAGU0PiwPBuhAkEJI-BJeANrN2WsctduPDJM97gKhUQ4AADDn27Ftgr2fptwrAzE99olsqbPyisxupAer1GH2u6fali6zi3KSyLjCMTVPy6f1LsxiDIAKgAfper1eVvxkjQ4AByTtNbGPunMgSs9hE2YnDNPhIm5yIoe5IKQOjvhyM6CsK9Z-kc9CPkEIJcri1qEhB2iPiqhgAEwAMx4Xh6RwKeGRBtOy46nK67wIOlIeDu1qQrowHbruPj7pkAZUceZ7XoJt40vebzPqhb4fiyhLbP+xzIeaQ6hIoLHgZUW6eGBWFQWszZwQiCEAQpL5YtE6H4j+2m4YRxHpORlF8XAK6xnq9EUiCO5gboJlcsI+ACPYlxqAiY5KIcfZEPg6lyJ5XFIAevGOSeF6CTe6byXihLvqOUZDF+wAEuwKBKBodxyUhMJIDMcw4fhREkWRFFHqYzlrvGDEeZxNRsTIMVddx-rJXA0gANYoG89nNU5NFxrcHWYrF3V2q+0Q7pV1Xwj1GmLQNRpDaN42NQ5fGtbR7XuQtYiqd5EmrfgEBjdQUXsewO3xTx+2PUdU2nbNbkWpd61wt0N2ctifkPYdmwFEgahqM9vUcV5H1nsNX2TY502rmdtw+eD91fdD1iw2oQwEigswI9t-XvYNqMHRNTXLv6CzaEAA)

Comment: The problem is that `<MyComponent isOpen={false} />` is expecting `withButton`, but I want it to expect `buttonText` (as `withButton` is true by default when not passed). Does that make sense?

Comment: IIUC, you are worried that the TS error indication hints about `withButton`, whereas you would like to emphasize on `buttonText` instead? In that case, it is just a matter of properly ordering your type union. I will edit above answer to clarify.

Comment: Oh my god, I was thinking that the FIRST one takes precedence, and never tried to reverse the order  Thank you so much!